# XSLT: How to count non duplicate nodes with condition

Tags: xslt, count

I have the following XML:

```
<messageList>

<message>
<type>L1</type>
<name>John</name>
</message>

<message>
<type>L2</type>
<name>Mary</name>
</message>

<message>
<type>L2</type>
<name>John</name>
</message>

<message>
<type>L2</type>
<name>John</name>
</message>

<message>
<type>L3</type>
<name>Sam</name>
</message>

<message>
<type>L3</type>
<name>Tom</name>
</message>

<message>
<type>L3</type>
<name>Rob</name>
</message>

</messageList>
```

How can I count **unique** names for **every** type?

i.e.:
L1: 1 (John)
L2: 2 (Mary, John)
L3: 3 (Sam, Tom, Rob)

How can I combine `count(//message[./name=not(.=preceding::*)])` and `type=$MSGTYPE` ?

(The overall goal is to make html table with rowspans (type>name>count of same names))

My current XLST:

```
[....]   
-------Loop at unique type--------
    <xsl:for-each select="//message/type[not(.=preceding::*)]">
    <tr>
       <xsl:variable name="MSGTYPE"> <xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>

-------Rowspan should be number of unique names-------
        <td rowspan = "{count(//JCOMessage[./JcoServerName=$MSGTYPE and ./MessageName ???not(.=preceding::*)])}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>

[....]
```

Comment: Are you using a current version of XSLT (i.e. 3)? Have you looked through https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info?

Comment: I'm limited to xslt 1.0 :-( But thanks, I will look through this link

Comment: If you expect people to help you with working code as they tested it against your input data I would suggest you edit your question and correct the various errors to ensure the XML input sample is well-formed.

Comment: Start by learning about Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keys and Muenchian grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="type-group" match="message" use="type"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="name-of-type-group" match="message" use="concat(type, '|', name)"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="message[generate-id() = generate-id(key('type-group', type)[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="name-group-headers" select="key('type-group', type)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('name-of-type-group', concat(type, '|', name))[1])]"/>
    <xsl:value-of 
       select="count($name-group-headers)"/>
    <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$name-group-headers/name"/>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="message[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('type-group', type)[1]))]"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2/3 this is way easier and more compact:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="messageList/message" group-by="type">
      <xsl:text>{current-grouping-key()}: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:variable name="names" select="distinct-values(current-group()/name)"/>
      <xsl:text>{count($names)} ({string-join($names, ', ')})&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 3 can be used in the browser with SaxonJS and under Node.js as well as on the Java platform with Saxon HE Java or on .NET with Saxon HE .NET or with C/C++/Python/PHP using SaxonC HE.